# Problema de validación con html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Buenas a todos,

Tengo un problema con la validación en htm5.

Se trata de un proyecto final, consiste en crear una aplicación web para dibujar con la Api de Canvas, un rectángulo, un circulo, una linea, y una curva además hay que almacenar los parámetros que se le ha introducido al formulario con la Api de sessionstorage, con esto se crea un texto que aparece en pantalla con los parámetros que se ha introducido
El caso es que las validación lo hago con html5 dándole cada input un min=0 y un max=600 o 500 (dependiendo de la anchura y la altura del canvas), Al igual añadiendo el atributo required según lo necesite. El botón tiene un evento onclick y llama a la función js que pinta según la figura geométrica seleccionada.

Todo funciona bien, pero cuando se añade valores incorrecto salta los mensajes de error, pero no se anula el evento, apareciendo el texto con los parámetros incorrecto. Coloco un ejemplo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro el código del rectangulo

```
<form role="form" name="formRectangulo" id="formRectangulo">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recEmpiezaX">Empieza X</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="recEmpiezaX" name="recEmpiezaX" min="0" max="600" placeholder="Escriba un numero entre 0 y 600" required> </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recEmpiezaY">Empieza Y</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="recEmpiezaY" name="recEmpiezaY" min="0" max="500" placeholder="Escriba un numero entre 0 y 500" required> </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recAncho">Ancho</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="recAncho" name="recAncho" placeholder="Escriba un numero" min="0" required> </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recAlto">Alto</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="recAlto" name="recAlto" placeholder="Escriba un numero" min="0" required> </div>
                        <!--Color borde-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recColorContorno">Color</label>
                            <input type="color" name="recColorContorno" id="recColorContorno" value="#FF0000">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="recTipoBorde" id="recTipoBorde" value="Contorno">  
                            <label for="recTipoBorde">Dibujar Contorno</label>
                        </div>
                        <!--Color Relleno-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recColorRelleno">Color</label>
                            <input type="color" name="recColorRelleno" id="recColorRelleno" value="#81F7F3">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="recTipoRelleno" id="recTipoRelleno" value="Relleno">  
                            <label for="recTipoRelleno">Dibujar Relleno</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" onclick="pintarRectangulo()">Pintar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" onclick="limpiar()">Limpiar Pantalla</button>
                    </form>
```

Muestro el código js

```
function pintarRectangulo() {
//Cojo los valores del formulario y lo pinta
var lienzo = iniciar();
var empiezaX = document.formRectangulo.recEmpiezaX.value;
var empiezaY = document.formRectangulo.recEmpiezaY.value;
var ancho = document.formRectangulo.recAncho.value;
var largo = document.formRectangulo.recAlto.value;
var conBorde = document.formRectangulo.recTipoBorde;
var conRelleno = document.formRectangulo.recTipoRelleno;
var colorBorde = document.getElementById("recColorContorno").value;
var colorRelleno = document.getElementById("recColorRelleno").value;
//Compruebo el checkbox
if (conBorde.checked && conRelleno.checked) {   
    //Relleno
    lienzo.fillStyle = colorRelleno;
    lienzo.fillRect(empiezaX, empiezaY, ancho, largo);
    //Borde
    lienzo.strokeStyle = colorBorde;
    lienzo.strokeRect(empiezaX, empiezaY, ancho, largo);
}
else if (conBorde.checked) {
    lienzo.strokeStyle = colorBorde;
    lienzo.strokeRect(empiezaX, empiezaY, ancho, largo);
}
else {
    lienzo.fillStyle = colorRelleno;
    lienzo.fillRect(empiezaX, empiezaY, ancho, largo);
}
//Funcion del localStorage
mostrarDatosRectangulos(empiezaX, empiezaY, ancho, largo, conBorde, conRelleno);
```

}

```
function mostrarDatosRectangulos(empiezaX, empiezaY, ancho, largo, conBorde, conRelleno) {
//Guardo todo en el localStorage
localStorage.setItem(empiezaX, empiezaX);
localStorage.setItem(empiezaY, empiezaY);
localStorage.setItem(ancho, ancho);
localStorage.setItem(largo, largo);
//Añado los valores en html
var informacion = document.getElementById('informacion');
var add = document.createElement('div');
add.className = "panel panel-default";
var add2 = document.createElement('div'); //Se coloca un segundo div
add2.className = "panel-body"; //Agregamos class
if (conBorde.checked && conRelleno.checked) {
    var colorBorde = document.getElementById("recColorContorno").value;
    var colorRelleno = document.getElementById("recColorRelleno").value;
    localStorage.setItem(colorBorde, colorBorde);
    localStorage.setItem(colorRelleno, colorRelleno);
    var contenido = 'Se ha pintando un rectangulo con la coordenada X = ' + localStorage.getItem(empiezaX) + 'px. Y = ' + localStorage.getItem(empiezaY) + 'px con un ancho de ' + localStorage.getItem(ancho) + 'px y con un alto de ' + localStorage.getItem(largo) + 'px con un color de borde: ' + localStorage.getItem(colorBorde) + ' y de relleno ' + localStorage.getItem(colorRelleno);
}
else if (conBorde.checked) {
    var colorBorde = document.getElementById("recColorContorno").value;
    localStorage.setItem(colorBorde, colorBorde);
    var contenido = 'Se ha pintando un rectangulo con la coordenada X = ' + localStorage.getItem(empiezaX) + 'px. Y = ' + localStorage.getItem(empiezaY) + 'px con un ancho de ' + localStorage.getItem(ancho) + 'px y con un alto de ' + localStorage.getItem(largo) + 'px con un color de borde: ' + localStorage.getItem(colorBorde);
}
else {
    var colorRelleno = document.getElementById("recColorRelleno").value;
    localStorage.setItem(colorRelleno, colorRelleno);
    var contenido = 'Se ha pintando un rectangulo con la coordenada X = ' + localStorage.getItem(empiezaX) + 'px. Y = ' + localStorage.getItem(empiezaY) + 'px con un ancho de ' + localStorage.getItem(ancho) + 'px y con un alto de ' + localStorage.getItem(largo) + 'px y con un color de relleno ' + localStorage.getItem(colorRelleno);
}
add2.innerHTML = contenido;
add.appendChild(add2);
informacion.appendChild(add);
```

}

Muchas gracias un saludo.

Comment: Puedes lograr lo que deseas usando la Propiedad preventDefault() de la WEB Api Event para detener (que no ocurra) el evento submit(), te dejo un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que deseas usando la Propiedad [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) de la [WEB Api Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) para detener (que no ocurra) el evento `submit()`, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Modificar el código ***HTML*** `<form ...>` e `<input type="submit" ...>` como sigue:

```
<form role="form" name="formRectangulo" id="formRectangulo"
onsubmit="pintarRectangulo()">
...
...
...
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-
block">Pintar</button>
```

Modificar el código ***javaScript*** `function pintarRectangulo() {...` como sigue:

```
function pintarRectangulo() {

// Prevenir el Evento submit():
event.preventDefault();

//Cojo los valores del formulario y lo pinta
var lienzo = iniciar();
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo resumido pero funcional:

```js
function pintarRectangulo() {

// Prevenir el Evento submit():
event.preventDefault();

console.log("pintar!!! ;))...");
}
```

```html
<form role="form" name="formRectangulo" id="formRectangulo"
onsubmit="pintarRectangulo()">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recEmpiezaX">Empieza X</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="recEmpiezaX" name="recEmpiezaX" min="0" max="600" placeholder="Escriba un numero entre 0 y 600" required> </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recEmpiezaY">Empieza Y</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="recEmpiezaY" name="recEmpiezaY" min="0" max="500" placeholder="Escriba un numero entre 0 y 500" required> </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recAncho">Ancho</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="recAncho" name="recAncho" placeholder="Escriba un numero" min="0" required> </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recAlto">Alto</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="recAlto" name="recAlto" placeholder="Escriba un numero" min="0" required> </div>
                        <!--Color borde-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recColorContorno">Color</label>
                            <input type="color" name="recColorContorno" id="recColorContorno" value="#FF0000">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="recTipoBorde" id="recTipoBorde" value="Contorno">  
                            <label for="recTipoBorde">Dibujar Contorno</label>
                        </div>
                        <!--Color Relleno-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recColorRelleno">Color</label>
                            <input type="color" name="recColorRelleno" id="recColorRelleno" value="#81F7F3">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="recTipoRelleno" id="recTipoRelleno" value="Relleno">  
                            <label for="recTipoRelleno">Dibujar Relleno</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-
block">Pintar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" onclick="limpiar()">Limpiar Pantalla</button>
                    </form>
```

Espero esto te ayude. Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: Me parece increíble, lo desconocía totalmente. Muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado y recuerda puntuar y calificar la respuesta que mas se adecue a tus requerimientos, Saludos!! ;)...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que el boton no se deshabilita aunque el valor del rango no sea válido y al momento se hacer click pues se ejecuta la función, te sugiero que hagas la validación por javascript al momento de ejecutar la función. 
También puedes deshabilitar el botón Pintar hasta que todos los campos requeridos estén completo y con su rango válido en el caso de los tipo range.

Comment: Es cierto lo que dices, se ejecuta igualmente el evento aunque se valide por el html (digamos que html te proporciona el mensaje, pero no te hace una validación real) por lo cual sí o sí hay que validar los input por js. Gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: Si, pero supongamos que tu formulario en vez de ejecutar una función por onclick, enviara datos por post a otra pagina por ejemplo en php, en ese caso la validación del formulario si funcionaria pues monstraria un mensaje diciendo que el rango no es valido al momento de intentar hacer el submit. pero como tiene un evento onclick no importa si los datos no son validos ese onclick se ejecuta si o si. Espero haberme explicado bien, suerte con tu proyecto.